# How can I provide a gallery for the system camera app on a fully managed phone

Tags: samsung, microsoft-intune

I have a fully managed (by Microsoft Intune) Samsung A34 phone, that comes with a system camera but no gallery.

I have added a third-party gallery app to our managed Play-Store along with a third party camera app. The third party apps work along nicely, however, the system camera app tells me that there's no app associated for this action, when I tap on the miniature image that the camera app shows of the last photo that was taken.

Is there a solution for this, or am I stuck with my third-party apps work-around.

Comment: The "system camera" should be the Samsung Camera app (com.sec.android.app.camera)  correct? It should be tied to the Samsung Gallery app (com.sec.android.gallery3d).

Comment: Well, the thing is: on the managed phone, there's no gallery app by default. On Google Play-Store, I am unable to find a gallery app from Samsung. I find a lot else from Samsung on Google Play, but apparently there's no gallery. Which brings me back to my original problem: how to tell the system camera to play nice with a third-party gallery? Am I missing something here? I mean, is this really a use case that nobody cared to think about, or even imagined?